# Retrieving data from multiple SQL tables with multiple related entries

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a database with three tables, related with foreign keys:

Trips:

```
ID
Number
Date
```

Days:

```
ID
TripID (Foreign key to ID column in trips)
Date
Start
End
```

Legs:

```
ID
DayID (Foreign key to ID column in days)
Origin
Destination
```

In my app, I have a Trip class, Day class, and Leg class corresponding to each table.  Each Trip has a list of associated Days, each Day has a list of associated Legs.  Currently I load the data from the database by running a query for the desired trip.  Then I run another query to fetch all the days associated with that trip and add those, then I run a query for each day to fetch the associated legs and add those.

It seems to me that there should be a more efficient way to accomplish this.  Is my only other option doing a triple join of the three tables and getting a cursor that has a row for each leg that also contains all of the day and trip data for that leg?  Is there a better way to do it?  I'm not too familiar with SQL queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join is the obvious answer:

```
SELECT * FOM Trips t JOIN Days d
ON t.Id = d.TripId
JOIN Legs l 
ON d.Id = l.DayId
WHERE t.Id = tripId
```

You'll need to replace `tripId` with the id of the trip you're trying to find.  A good idea is to also replace `*` with the actual columns you need returned to your application.